# Doing something when user click the BackButton

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to do something when the user clicks the hardware button on the phone. I have two pages. In the App.xaml.cs I've added the following code to handling the navigation to and from the pages.

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

But now I want to do something else when the user clicks the back button. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure about what you want but you just have to replace "if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        this.Frame.GoBack();" and set your code there. OnBackRequested will always be call when you will click on the back button.

Comment: I could do so, but I need to do different things on each page of my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the back button to do something different on each page, then you will need to handle the Back button on each page - I do this to prompt the user to confirm losing their changes on one of my pages.

Subscribe to the BackRequested event in each page's OnNavigatedTo method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += this.OnBackPressed;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

And make sure you unsubscribe in the page's OnNavigatedFrom method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= this.OnBackPressed;
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}
```

Now you can write a OnBackPressed() event handler on each page that does what you want it to do on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "doing something" with running a method before going back, you can use `Page` navigation methods for that

[`OnNavigatingFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for "Invoked immediately before the Page is unloaded and is no longer the current source of a parent Frame."

[`OnNavigatinTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) for "Invoked when the Page is loaded and becomes the current source of a parent Frame."

[`OnNavigatedFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom.aspx) for "Invoked immediately after the Page is unloaded and is no longer the current source of a parent Frame."

such as

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string productID;
    DataServiceContext svcContext = 
        new DataServiceContext(new Uri("AdventureWorks.svc", UriKind.Relative));

    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ProductId"))
    {
        productID = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["ProductId"];
    }
    else
    {
        productID = App.Current.Resources["FeaturedProductID"].ToString();
    }

    svcContext.BeginExecute<Product>(new Uri("Product(" + productID + ")", 
        UriKind.Relative), loadProductCallback, svcContext);

}
```